# Question about convection heat transfer in the dynamic pipe of the modelica standard library fluid

Tags: fluid, modelica, openmodelica

So I'm new to the tool openmodelica and I'm trying to simulate the flow of a fluid in a pipe with heat transfer.

Here's the configuration: a fluid with an inlet pressure and temperature flow through a pipe, the outside temperature is higher than the inlet fluid temperature. The pressure in the outlet of the pipe is inferior to the inlet pressure to allow the flow of the fluid.

[image: Example model]

I assigned a material to the wall of pipe using `WallConstProps`. I want to simulate the convection heat transfer between the wall and the ambient so I used the convection component of the thermal library. I have attached a picture of my current system.

My question is : to simulate the convection heat transfert between the wall and the fluid, do I have to just connect the Wall to the `heatport` of the dynamic pipe and set the use_HeatTransfer to "true"?

Moreover, I don't really understand how the `heatports` of the `Wallconstprops` and the dynamic pipe. When I connect them, I have to select which `heatport` to use, so does the heat transfer apply to the whole component or just to the segment of the component corresponding to that `heatport`?

Thanks in advance and have a great day,
Maxime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convective heat transfer of the fluid inside the pipe can be specified with the parameter `HeatTransfer` in the `Assumptions` tab of the `DynamicPipe` model. The drop-down menu gives you different heat transfer correlations to choose from. The default `IdealHeatTransfer` has no (convective) thermal resistance — that is the temperatures of the fluid volumes are equal to the `heatPort` temperatures. You might want to use `LocalPipeFlowHeatTransfer` which models the fluid convective heat transfer under both laminar and turbulent conditions.

As for your second question: Since the `DynamicPipe` model is discretized in `nNodes` segments, when you connect the pipe to the wall model (discretized in `n` segments) you are asked which segments to connect. Accepting the default `[:]` pipe segments `1:nNodes` are connected to wall segments `1:n`. Obviously, the number of wall and pipe segments should be equal. In the wall model you could set `n=pipe.nNodes`.

The default value of `nNodes` is 2. If you want to use only one segment you also need to change the model structure of the pipe with the parameter `modelStructure` to one different from `av_vb`. This parameter can be found in the `Advanced` tab.

Comment: Hi Rene,thanks for the quick answer. When I go to the Advanced tab of the DynamicPipe model, I have four sections : nNodes, modelStructure, useLumpedPressure and useInnerPortProperties. I can't find the menu to choose the type of Heatransfer. Maybe I'm not looking at the right place. About the second question I've solved the problem thanks to you but I have another question. When I connect the component convection to the WallConstProps component, as the convection component has only one port, should I use one covection component for each port of the wall and reduce the value of the source ?

Comment: Sorry, the `HeatTransfer` parameter is in the `Assumptions` tab. Yes, you should instantiate `nNodes` convection models and connect each of them to the wall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the Assumptions tab, in the section HeatTransfer, I set the use_HeatTransfer value to "true". Is it what you meant in your first answer to take into account the convective heat transfer of the fluid into the pipe ?

Comment: No, setting `use_HeatTransfer=true` only exposes the `heatPort` and connects it to the internal fluid temperatures. If you want to model the convective heat transfer (flow regime, Nusselt number etc.) you'll have to choose a different heat transfer model than the default (`IdealHeatTransfer`) — as described in the answer.

Comment: Ok, but in the Assumptions tab, I only have the Parameters section, the Dynamic section and the HeatTransfer section. And in the HeatTranfer section, I only have the possibility to change the value of use_HeatTransfer. Where can I find the section to change the model of heat transfer ?

Comment: In OpenModelica v1.18.0 I see the two parameters (`use_HeatTransfer` and `HeatTransfer`) in the `Heat transfer` section of the `Assumptions` tab.

Comment: Ok that's weird. The temperatures of my medium in the different segments of the pipeare changing so I guess it means that the heatPort and the internal fluid are connected. When you're talking about flow regime, Nusselt number do you mean it should appear in the results after the simulation ?

Comment: I was just referring to the type of governing equations used in the mentioned heat transfer model

Comment: Hi Rene, after looking a little bit more, I found in Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer, different models of HeatTransfer such as the LocalPipeFlowHeatTransfer. I tried to redeclare the model of HeatTransfer inside the pipe in the text editor by using the line : redeclare model HeatTransfer=Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.LocalPipeFlowHeatTransfer                       . The check of the model is ok but the simulation is not running. Do you have any idea if it's the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, the syntax looks correct to me. If you can't get the simulation to run, you should create a new post explaining what you have tried, the error message(s) and the Modelica code of your model.